# Error with storybook when using native base

Tags: react-native, storybook, native-base

I'm using storybook with react native. I used react-native-web to display my components in the storybook on the browser and it worked. But whenever I integrate native base, by only importing its components, I get the following error:

in ./node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image/AssetSourceResolver.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../Utilities/Platform' in 'D:\projects\testingStorybook\SomethingElse\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Image'

Note that I was able to load static images in the storybook and native base components loaded successfully on my android emulator.

dependencies:

```
"@babel/preset-env": "^7.16.11",
"@babel/preset-react": "^7.16.7",
"html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
"native-base": "^3.3.4",
"react": "17.0.2",
"react-native": "0.67.2",
"react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.3.2",
"react-native-storybook-loader": "^2.0.5",
"react-native-svg": "^12.1.1",
"react-native-web": "^0.17.5"
```

devDependencies:

```
"@babel/core": "7.16.12",
"@babel/runtime": "7.16.7",
"@react-native-community/eslint-config": "2.0.0",
"@storybook/addon-actions": "^6.4.17",
"@storybook/addon-essentials": "^6.4.17",
"@storybook/addon-knobs": "^5.3.21",
"@storybook/addon-links": "^6.4.17",
"@storybook/addon-ondevice-actions": "^5.3.23",
"@storybook/addon-ondevice-knobs": "^5.3.25",
"@storybook/react": "^6.4.17",
"@storybook/react-native": "^5.3.25",
"@storybook/react-native-server": "^5.3.23",
"babel-jest": "26.6.3",
"babel-loader": "^8.2.3",
"eslint": "7.14.0",
"eslint-plugin-storybook": "^0.5.6",
"jest": "26.6.3",
"metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.66.2",
"react-dom": "^17.0.2",
"react-test-renderer": "17.0.2"
```

Answer (score 0):

React native storybook is not compatible with storybook 6.4.

You should change these to use either 5.3 or 6.3 depending on your usuage of storybook

```
"@storybook/addon-links": "^6.4.17",
"@storybook/react": "^6.4.17",
"@storybook/addon-actions": "^6.4.17",
```